# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null when running JavaScript code in Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to run following code by saving it as Chrome bookmarklet.

```
javascript:(function(){var myslidetotal=document.evaluate('//*[@id="total-slides"]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML;
var myslideurl=document.evaluate('//*[@id="container"]/img', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.src;
myslideurl=myslideurl.substring(0,myslideurl.indexOf("/images/")+8);
for(var ii=0;ii<myslidetotal;ii++){var myslideuniqurl=myslideurl+ii+'.jpeg?dpr=1&fit=clip&w=768';window.open(myslideuniqurl); }
})();
```

But it gives me error.
VM1747:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

But when I try running same code in console. It works perfectly.

Why is this anomaly while running code and how to rectify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome's now getting better by not executing some JavaScript that manipulate DOM on the URLs using `javascript:` protocol. So, yea, this implementation will fail. `:)` It's a security feature.

More Information: [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

> *But it works in Console...*

Using the Chrome Developer Console (or any of the current <kbd>F12</kbd> Developer Tools), one can even get your Cookies, Session Information, and Credentials. Console has full power. `:)` In simple terms, your JavaScript console is like your Admin Account for JavaScript in Web Sites.

> *Any Work Arounds?*

**No.** But one can create an extension or [UserScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey#Userscripts.org) and run it using [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) for Google Chrome. Firefox has an extension called [GreaseMonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey).

Comment: But same code runs when put in console. Why doesnt chrome secure itself there.??

Comment: @ChahitKumar Using console, I can even get your cookies and credentials. Console has full power buddy. `:)` In simple terms, your JavaScript console is like your admin account for JavaScript in Web Sites.

Comment: @ChahitKumar **No.** But you can create an extension or [UserScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey#Userscripts.org) and run it using [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) for Google Chrome.

Comment: @ChahitKumar Did my answer help you?

Comment: I created a Tampermonkey userscript with exactly the same code that worked in console, but the `evaluate` didn't work even there as I got `null` just like in a bookmarklet.